# Update MySQL DB to Compress Blobs

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, compression

If there a one-shot way to update a range of IDs (e.g. WHERE `ID`>10 AND `ID`<1000) to compress a blob column (e.g. `data`)?

e.g.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `data`=(SELECT COMPRESS(`data`) FROM `table` WHERE ID=1) WHERE ID=1
```

but for a range of IDs instead of a single ID.  I need to update around 1500 rows that were incorrectly inserted into a DB without compression.

Answer (score 5):

Wont this work?:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `data`=  COMPRESS(`data`) WHERE ID > 10 AND ID < 1000
```

Comment: yup; durh.  Obvious answer to obvious problem.  Cheers